# im trying to run a python code in MobaXterm

Tags: python, mobaxterm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVDO3.png)
It says module speech_recognition not found.
I had speech_recognition module downloaded in my environment. Only have 1 which is base. I managed to run the code on my visual studio code. But unable to run on my MobaXterm as it says speech_recognition module not found.
Even tried to uninstall SpeechRecognition and install it back

Comment: Did you install using pip, 'pip install SpeechRecognition'? You can try 'pip freeze' and check if the module is installed.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add a comment yet but have you installed the PyAudio module aswell? I remember I ran into a similar issue in pycharm
Also if you added speech recognition using pip install, it wouldnt hurt to try using sudo pip aswell